# sales price prediction

Tags: classification, regression, prediction

I have to find make a classifier for price prediction of a item. The question I have is which columns I should choose for price prediction.

Also which machine learning classifier would be good to perform this, at present I choose random forest.

Do I need to use time series concept in here?, I think No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly, what do you mean by "classifier for price prediction"? You can predict the price as a number, that would like be different for different cars, but if you want to predict a class of price (like, high, low and medium for instance), you would need a column for that (and you can ignore the column for price, as you are not predicting the price, you're predicting the price class).

**Stage 1. Pre-processing the data**

Assuming you have the column in the dataset which you want to predict for, you first want to do feature selection. That is, not all features in the data would be important or relevant for predicting the price. For example, in your dataset, the first column/feature ("index") is irrelevant for the price of the car. But how do we prove that? Or, how do we computationally select them (using some measure), especially when they're not as trivial as "index"?

We generally check the statistical properties of the features for that. I copied the data you provided in the question, and here's some things for you to start with:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('ex.csv')
data
```

[image]

```
data.describe() # to check the statistical properties of the features, like mean, std dev, etc
```

[image]

Then, you could do a simple percentage count of the unique observations in each feature, and maybe you could get some insight about the features that way:

```
for column in data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    display(pd.crosstab(index=data[column], columns='% observations', normalize='columns'))
```

[image]

Then you could do a histogram analysis of the features and hopefully that gives you some more insight. For example, assuming you have sufficiently enough data, you'd normally expect the histogram of a feature to follow the normal or gaussian distribution. But if its doesn't, then you can further drill down into those features to understand why, and that might lead you to keep or discard those features from the model you're going to build.

```
hist = data.hist(figsize=(10, 10))
```

[image]

Then we can do correlation analysis of the features:

```
data.corr().style.background_gradient()
```

[image]

Or, if you want a more fancy visualization:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(data.corr(), annot=True)
```

[image]

After doing all these, hopefully you have figured out which features to discard and which to keep for your model. These are of course "manual" methods of feature selection; there are other more complex methods for feature selection like SHAPLEY values, etc, which you can explore.

**Stage 2 - Building a model and training it**

Firstly, you need to pick a technique/method using which you want to do the prediction. The simplest one, since you have only one target variable (i.e., only one feature you're predicting, which is the price or the price class), the simplest one would be linear regression, and the most complicated ones would be some deep learning model build with CNN or RNN. So, instead of showing you how to make predictions with the simplest one, i.e., linear regression, let me show you a middle-of-the-road algorithm in terms of complexity which is quite popular and a widely used method in many machine learning tasks, the accelerated gradient boost, or xgboost, algorithm.

We need to import some libraries for this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost
import numpy as np

X = data.drop(['price'], axis=1) # take all the features except the target variable
y = data['price'] # the target variable
```

Then, we create a train/test split with 80-20 split randomly. That is, we randomly take 80% data for training and 20% for testing:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

You can of course do a 70-30 split if you want, and definitely try out different splits at both ends of the spectrum to see what happens - that way you'll learn more about why a 70-30 or 80-20 split is good and, say, a 50-50 split is not that good.

Then, if there are missing values in your data, fill them with a high negative value so that it doesn't have any impact in the model. You can also choose to fill them with something else, depending on your goal.

```
X_train.fillna((-999), inplace=True)
X_test.fillna((-999), inplace=True)
```

Some more preprocessing steps:

```
# Some of values are float or integer and some object. This is why we need to cast them:
from sklearn import preprocessing 
for f in X_train.columns: 
    if X_train[f].dtype=='object': 
        lbl = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
        lbl.fit(list(X_train[f].values)) 
        X_train[f] = lbl.transform(list(X_train[f].values))

for f in X_test.columns: 
    if X_test[f].dtype=='object': 
        lbl = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
        lbl.fit(list(X_test[f].values)) 
        X_test[f] = lbl.transform(list(X_test[f].values))


X_train=np.array(X_train) 
X_test=np.array(X_test) 
X_train = X_train.astype(float) 
X_test = X_test.astype(float)

d_train = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train, feature_names=list(X))
d_test = xgboost.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test, feature_names=list(X))
```

Finally, we can make our model and train it:

```
params = {
    "eta": 0.01, # something called the learning rate - read up about optimization and gradient descent to understand more about this
    "subsample": 0.5,
    "base_score": np.mean(y_train)
}

# these params are optional - if you don't feed the train function below with the params, it will take the default values

model = xgboost.train(params, d_train, 5000, evals = [(d_test, "test")], verbose_eval=100, early_stopping_rounds=50)
```

You can check the root mean square error (RMSE) that this function returns at the end to see how good or bad the training has been (low RMSE is good, high RMSE is bad - but there's no max RMSE value, it can be arbitrarily high). There are other methods to check the error, and you can explore them (like MAE, etc), but this is probably the simplest one. Anyway, the above code will return something like this:

```
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[0] test-rmse:2275
Will train until test-rmse hasn't improved in 50 rounds.
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:02] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 6 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[16:56:03] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
Stopping. Best iteration:
[0] test-rmse:1571.88
```

It ran the algo iteratively 5000 times, printing out the result every 100 lines (that's what those numbers are in the train method). To see what each of the parameters mean, you can read [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#general-parameters).

You can also use linear regression, if you want, with xgboost, like so:

```
xg_reg = xgboost.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', colsample_bytree = 0.3, learning_rate = 0.1,
                max_depth = 5, alpha = 10, n_estimators = 10)

xg_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

preds = xg_reg.predict(X_test) 
print(preds) # these are the predicted prices for the test data
>>> array([2293.7073, 2891.9692, 3822.3757], dtype=float32)
```

And we can check the RMSE like so:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, preds))
print("RMSE: %f" % (rmse))
>>> RMSE: 1542.541395
```

Note that RMSE in the 2 methods is quite close (1571.88 vs 1542.54). This is like a sanity check for us that no matter which method we use, if we use it correctly, we should get similar results.

**Stage 3 - testing and evaluation of the model - k-fold Cross Validation**

Finally its time to see how our model performs on test data:

```
params = {"objective":"reg:linear",'colsample_bytree': 0.3,'learning_rate': 0.1,
                'max_depth': 5, 'alpha': 10}

cv_results = xgboost.cv(dtrain=d_train, params=params, nfold=3,
                    num_boost_round=50,early_stopping_rounds=10,metrics="rmse", as_pandas=True)
```

This will again give you quite a few lines of output like when training:

```
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 0 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=0
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 4 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=2
[17:38:33] C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xgboost\src\tree\updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 2 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=1
```

This is how it looks in each of the rounds of the boosting:

```
print(cv_results)
```

[image]

So, that's it. We have the predicted values.

**P.S. Stage 2.5 - Visualizing the model (Optional)**

Did you know that we can also visualize the model?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xgboost.plot_tree(xg_reg,num_trees=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It shows the tree structure following which the model you trained made its decisions.

You can also see the importance of each feature in the dataset with respect to the model:

```
xgboost.plot_importance(xg_reg)
plt.show()
```

[image]

These visualizations are of course not required for making the predictions, but they may sometimes give you useful insights about your predictions.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use time series concept here. You have to do a pair plot analysis to find your best predictor. I do not think index column is much useful here. I feel length, width or breadth are features if you classify the vehicles as sedan, suv or small car. Not sure if it be of much help in predicting the price. If you add more breadth to the dataset, make sure you have enough depth or training examples

Do a heat map and find the co-relation between the feature and target variable as well. You can remove those features which does not have good co-relation with the target variable.

Try to start with Linear regression model, since you have to predict the price. then move on to more complex models. Random forest regressor is also a good choice for smaller datasets